# Concurrent map/foreach in scala

Tags: scala, concurrency, functional-programming

I have an iteration `vals: Iterable[T]` and a long-running function without any relevant side effects: `f: (T => Unit)`. Right now this is applied to `vals` in the obvious way:

```
vals.foreach(f)
```

I would like the calls to `f` to be done concurrently (within reasonable limits). Is there an obvious function somewhere in the Scala base library? Something like:

```
Concurrent.foreach(8 /* Number of threads. */)(vals, f)
```

While `f` is reasonably long running, it is short enough that I don't want the overhead of invoking a thread for each call, so I am looking for something based on a thread pool.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like the `Futures` answer.  However, while it will execute concurrently, it will also return asynchronously, which is probably not what you want.  The correct approach would be as follows:

```
import scala.actors.Futures._

vals map { x => future { f(x) } } foreach { _() }
```

Comment: Be careful that `vals` is a strict collection -- if it's lazy (and in Scala 2.7 this includes the `Range` class), the futures won't be created until each one is needed by `foreach`, and nothing will happen in parallel.

Comment: I suppose we could solve that problem by injecting another `foreach` call between the `map` and the current `foreach`.  Thus: `vals map { x => future { f(x) } } foreach { x => x } foreach { _() }`

Comment: That would be a map we have to inject, not another foreach? And it is not clear to me that the map of a lazy collection is strict. The safest way may be to call toArray.

Comment: You're right, `foreach` was (obviously) the wrong thing to inject since it returns `Unit`.  My bad!  :-)

The `map` function on lazy collections is almost always non-strict, so we can either call `toList` (or `toArray`), or we can project and then force: `(vals map { x => future { f(x) } } projection).force foreach { _() }`.  I don't know whether that's *better* than simply `toList`, but it is certainly different.

Comment: What does it mean when you say it "returns asynchronously"? Does it imply that it is non-blocking? (and why would that be a problem?)

Comment: Any insight on what to use now that [that library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-actors/2.11.12) is deprecated?

Answer (score 23):

Many of the answers from 2009 still use the old scala.actors.Futures._, which are no longer in the newer Scala. While Akka is the preferred way, a much more readable way is to just use parallel (**.par**) collections:

`vals.foreach { v => f(v) }`

becomes

`vals.par.foreach { v => f(v) }`

Alternatively, using parMap can appear more succinct though with the caveat that you need to remember to import the usual Scalaz*. As usual, there's more than one way to do the same thing in Scala!

Answer (score 13):

[Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/) has `parMap`. You would use it as follows:

```
import scalaz.Scalaz._
import scalaz.concurrent.Strategy.Naive
```

This will equip every functor (including `Iterable`) with a `parMap` method, so you can just do:

```
vals.parMap(f)
```

You also get `parFlatMap`, `parZipWith`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I had some issues using scala.actors.Futures in Scala 2.8 (it was buggy when I checked).  Using java libs directly worked for me, though:

```
final object Parallel {
  val cpus=java.lang.Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors
  import java.util.{Timer,TimerTask}
  def afterDelay(ms: Long)(op: =>Unit) = new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask {override def run = op},ms)
  def repeat(n: Int,f: Int=>Unit) = {
    import java.util.concurrent._
    val e=Executors.newCachedThreadPool //newFixedThreadPool(cpus+1)
    (0 until n).foreach(i=>e.execute(new Runnable {def run = f(i)}))
    e.shutdown
    e.awaitTermination(Math.MAX_LONG, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `scala.actors.Futures`:

```
vals.foreach(t => scala.actors.Futures.future(f(t)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The latest release of [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org) has some higher-order concurrency features that you can use.

```
import fjs.F._
import fj.control.parallel.Strategy._
import fj.control.parallel.ParModule._
import java.util.concurrent.Executors._

val pool = newCachedThreadPool
val par = parModule(executorStrategy[Unit](pool))
```

And then...

```
par.parMap(vals, f)
```

Remember to `shutdown` the `pool`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Parallel Collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html) from the Scala standard library.
They're just like ordinary collections, but their operations run in parallel. You just need to put a `par` call before you invoke some collections operation.

```
import scala.collection._

val array = new Array[String](10000)
for (i <- (0 until 10000).par) array(i) = i.toString
```