# Iterating through a list using parallelism

Tags: scala, concurrency, parallel-processing, scalatest

I would like to speed up this within a test.

```
listOfUrls.map(url => {
    "call the url" should "return 200" in {
       requesting page and check for HTTP-Code
    }
}
```

The problem is that this approach is sequentially. Is it possible with scalatest/scala to use parallelism for this map? E.g.: Requesting an page every 2 seconds? Or Using an specified amount of threads?

Comment: does this answer help ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129890/5986907

Comment: Aren't ScalaTest tests already run in parallel?